# How to create a simple paclet archive file without documentation?

Tags: paclets

How to create a simple paclet file that I can distribute within my company. I just want use a simple mechanism that will create a folder in the base directory (`$BaseDirectory\Applications` or `$UserBaseDirectory\Applications`).

The folder will have the following structure:

```
$BaseDirectory\Application\MyPackage

\MyPackage.wl
\Other.wl
\Binaries\[some DLLs and Exes]
\Data\[some data files]
\SQLScripts\[some SQL scripts]
```

Then the code inside the `MyPackage.wl` together with `Other.wl` will take care of how to use the other files in this directory structure.

All I want the user to do is when I give them `MyPaclet-1.0.0.paclet` file to just install it and use it as follows:

```
PacletInstall["...path...\SamplePaclet-1.0.paclet"]

Needs["MyPackage`"]
```

Then all the top-level user functions are accessible within their session. Also, I want to be able to keep updating the paclet archive over time so if they can just `PacletUninstall["MyPaclet-1.0.0.paclet"]` and install the newer version from the updated paclet archive file that I will provide them.

So How do I create such a paclet archive file that will unpack in these directories?

Note: I don't care about documentation, just a simple mechanism as I described. I will add usage message to functions in the `.wl` files.

Comment: Read "tutorial/Paclets" in the help.